# Irreducibility of a Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chain

This is a very basic concept, which I'm confused with. I'm struggling to understand why a chain having the transition probabilities shown below would be considered irreducible as I thought every element in the Transition Matrix had to be positive, but in this case there are elements with Zeros.

Given the Markov Chain with state space ${0,1,2,3,4,5,6}$ and transition probabilities $p(0,0) = 0.75$, $p(0,1) = 0.25$, $p(1,0) = 0.5$, $p(1,1) = 0.25$, $p(1,2) = 0.25$, $p(6,0) = 0.25$, $p(6,5) = 0.25$, $p(6,6) = 0.5$, $p(j,0) = p(j,j-1) = p(j,j) = p(j,j+1) = 0.25$

**The answer for this question is that it is irreducible and every state communicates with each other.** I am trying to understand what this statement means.

Thank You

Comment: Have you reviewed the definitions of "irreducible" and "communicates"?  What do they say?

Comment: @whuber One of the definitions I read for irreducibility states that the Transition Matrix is one will all elements being positive. That's why I'm slightly confused, as we have zeros in this transition matrix. I can infer what "communication" between states means, which is for example that the chain can go from State 1 to State 6 by traversing through other states. Its just that definition that's holding me back.

Comment: If that's your definition of irreducibility, then you're correct: this chain is not irreducible. However, this is not the usual meaning. (The [usual meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Reducibility) refers to nonzero probabilities of transitions *that might possibly need more than one step*.)  If you have any reference materials from the same source as this question, you should attempt to find what *their* definition of "irreducible" is and apply that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path $0\to1\to2\to3\to4\to5\to6\to0$ has positive probability hence the chain is irreducible.

(Additionally, the transition $0\to0$ has positive probability hence the chain is aperiodic.)

Answer (score 4):

For such a simple Markov chain model the best way to approach this is to draw the diagram. The chain is irreducible if you can reach any other state from all states.